# unable to insert url in mysql database using php

Tags: php, mysql

Html code:

```
<input type="file" class="form-control" name="video[]" placeholder=" Enter Image file">
<div><h2>OR</h2></div>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="yurl" placeholder=" Enter youtube embedded code">
<button type='submit' name="save" class='btn btn-success waves-effect waves-light'><i class='fa fa-upload'></i> Save</button>
```

php code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['save'])){
    $yurl = ($_POST['yurl']); 
    $new_data=mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, stripslashes($yurl));
    echo $yurl;
    foreach($_FILES["video"]["tmp_name"] as $key=>$tmp_name){
        $temp = $_FILES["video"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        $name = $_FILES["video"]["name"][$key];
        if(empty($temp))
        {
            break;
        }

        move_uploaded_file($temp,"../uploads/galleryvideos/".$name); 
        $sql = "INSERT INTO gallaryvids (video ,youtube)
        VALUES ('$name', '$yurl')";

        if (mysqli_query($connection,$sql)) {
?>
        <script>
            window.location.href = "view_gal_video.php";

        </script>
<?php
        }
    }   
}
```

?>

Url which I want to insert: `https://youtu.be/sA0-QXbLnaE`

both video and link get inserted
when i only want to insert link not a video it fails but don't gives any error

Comment: Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Does it move the vid into your file system?

Comment: I dont see you connecting to the database! Did you?

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes.

Comment: Errrr Is that No to getting the Vid or NO to connection to database

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes There is a db connection in my own file

Comment: **What** You changed No to Yes and now I understand even less

Comment: @RiggsFolly sorry but now yes the file is moving...

Comment: Also, you do realise that you are outputting the `<script>      window.location.href = "view_gal_video.php";</script>` in the loop so you will run `n` javascript redirects all in one big bang

Comment: if your `mysqli_query()` call returns `false` then you can check what went wrong by using `mysqli_error()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated code with database connection.

```
if(isset($_POST['save'])){

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$yurl = $_POST['yurl'];
//$video='test';


foreach($_FILES["video"]["tmp_name"] as $key=>$tmp_name){
        $temp = $_FILES["video"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        $name = $_FILES["video"]["name"][$key];
        if(empty($temp))
        {
            break;
        }
        move_uploaded_file($temp,"../uploads/galleryvideos/".$name); 


$sql = "INSERT INTO gallaryvids (video, youtube)VALUES ('$name', '$yurl')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
}
```

Comment: thank you.It Works.But There is still an issue not an error.When i only want to insert url not a video it did not insert the url.

Comment: @sumitshelar you should at least upvote or accept the answer, downvote does not make sense